# Hide My Email and forwarded calendar invites - does meeting host see my real email when forwarding?

Tags: email, calendar, icloud-plus

I recently signed up for a webinar using a "Hide My" email, and Apple forwarded the calendar invite to my real email address (Gmail). In the invitees list, I see my Hide My email, my real email, and the webinar host. Does anyone know if the marketer gains access to my real email in this case, since calendar invites are often configured to notify the host when invites are forwarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that it does.

If the Marketer (Apple contractor) uses Exchange on their backend (very likely considering Exchange is the market leader), if a Meeting request is forwarded, the meeting organizer *can* be notified when and by whom it was forwarded by when the recepient accepts the meeting.

From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forward-a-meeting-94f2df68-8109-4334-8bfa-f5c013dc1578):

> If you want to invite someone to a meeting you haven't organized, you can forward the meeting to them. When the recipient receives the meeting request, it appears to come from the meeting organizer and the meeting organizer receives notification that you forwarded the meeting.

The [Google Business support site](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37161?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cforward-a-calendar-invitation-email), doesn’t indicate that meeting forwards can be identified.  However, it does state the following that indicates any changes they make will be on your behalf which would identify you as the person who forwarded the invite:

> If you forward an invitation, the recipient might be able to see updated meeting details and could change your RSVP response at any time.

As for the other messaging/calendaring servers (remaining ~30% market share), there’s simply too many to investigate.  I would take the stance of assuming they do share the info to be safe.